# missing symbols in mathmode

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to insert a couple of numbered equations into a latex document, the equation is very basic yet all the normal operators =, + and - don't appear when I compile the document.  I commented everything out except for the equation and still get the same output so I don't think it is as a result of anything before it in the document.  This is the first document I'm writing using latex so chances are its something really basic!!
the two equations are

```
\begin{equation} 
Z = \frac{c_o - 4c_p}{c_{Si} + Rc_M } - 2
\end{equation}
```

and

```
\begin{equation} 
NC = 4 - 2Z
\end{equation}
```

This is the header to the document

```
\usepackage{baththesis}
\usepackage[small,it]{caption}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=4cm, right=2.5cm,includeheadfoot,head=3cm, headsep=6ex, headheight=4ex]{geometry} % setting page to A4
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{multirow, array, textcomp, placeins, rotating, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, acronym, graphicx, subfig, setspace}
\usepackage{isotope}% package for isotopes [#]{element}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} %package for checmical compositions ce{composition}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: The package `baththesis` doesn't seem to be included in texlive full, and commenting it out doesn't solve the problem, so I suggest it can be removed from the MWE.

Comment: Commenting out `\usepackage{fouriernc}` does solve the problem (but changes the aspect of the equation as well).

Comment: It seems it depends by some interferences by `fouriernc` and `txfonts`. It is not present when one uses `newtxtext` but it is still present with `newtxmath`. Also inverting the order of loading the `fouriernc` and `txtext` solves it.

Comment: Loading both `fouriernc` and `txfonts` doesn't make sense. Use only either one of them. If you prefer Times to New Century Schoolbook, then try `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` instead of `\usepackage{txfonts}`

Comment: @egreg Perhaps make that an answer

Answer (score 2):

Loading both `fouriernc` and `txfonts` doesn't make sense. Use only either one of them.

If you prefer Times to New Century Schoolbook, then try

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{txfonts}
```

The `newtx` packages solve the spacing problems of the original TX fonts.